# If I select multiple records with ckeck box i want ids on that selected recods

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I have check box in data table if I select multiple first 3 records with check box after click on button I get ids like this `id=1&id=2id=3` and I want ids number only and separate like this `1,2,3`

```
function allAreEqual(aarray) {
    if (!aarray.length) return false;
    return aarray.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return (a === b) ? a : (!b);
    }) === aarray[0];
}

$(function() {
    $('#create_challan').click(function() {
        var allVals = [];
        var saleid = [];
        var buttonp = $(this);
        buttonp.addClass('disabled');
        buttonp.html(working);
        $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').each(function() {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
            saleid.push($(this).attr('saleid'));
        });

        if (allAreEqual(saleid)) {
            $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/' + user_type + '/' + module + '/create_invoice_pdf', {
                    <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
                    saleid: saleid[0],
                    val: allVals
                },
                function(data, status) {
                    window.open(base_url + 'invoices/' + data, '_blank');
                    window.focus();
                    location.reload();
                });
        } else {
            bootbox.alert("<b><br><br>Selection Error!</b>");
            buttonp.removeClass('disabled');
            buttonp.html('Create Invoice');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You mean on this property `val: allVals` ?

Comment: "I get ids like this id=1&id=2id=3"...where exactly are you seeing that value? If you're looking at the HTTP request body then that's expected - that's how you transmit values in a HTTP request. Although they will just over-write each other so you'd need to give them separate names, or use `[]`. More clarify over where you're seeing this info exactly would help a lot

Comment: P.S. I notice that after your $.post request succeeds you are doing "location.reload()". Since you're going to just refresh the page immediately in this case, what was the reason for using AJAX? A normal form postback would be easier to handle, require less code and could have the same effect - make a request, load the required page afterwards. The whole purpose of AJAX is to allow you to _stay on the same page_. Redirecting the user immediately after AJAX completes entirely defeats the point of using it.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle that on jquery level directly

for example:- 
if you have 5 cells in one row
set one cell like

```
<tr>
<td class='idcontainer' data-id='myid'>any-other-data</td>
</tr>
```

the `data-id` will store the id for every item in each row

on click of the `submit` button

you need to apply forloop for each `<tr>` find its child TD like `$('td.idcontainer').data('id');`

and store them in an array which is NOT LOCAL VARIABLE